# Did any airline successfully sue a passenger for hidden city ticketing?

Tags: united-states, air-travel

I sometimes see articles about airlines suing around for [hidden city ticketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Airline_booking_ploys&oldid=1165260477#Hidden-city_ticketing), e.g. see: [An airline is suing a customer who skipped a leg of his flight to save money](https://www.vox.com/the-goods/2019/2/13/18223833/lufthansa-sues-passenger-hidden-city-ticketing) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://www.vox.com/the-goods/2019/2/13/18223833/lufthansa-sues-passenger-hidden-city-ticketing)).

Did any airline successfully sue a passenger for hidden city ticketing?

I am mostly interested in US jurisdictions and US airlines but I am curious about other jurisdictions and airlines too.

Comment: In fact, no airline failed, or pursued such a suit to court judgment. In the one attested case, the suit was dropped.